# Strip timestamp info based on criteria using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'login_datetime':['5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM','09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM','06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM','06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM','12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM'],
                   'logout_datetime':['15/7/2013 09:27:00 AM','09/08/2013','06/06/2014 08:00:00','06/06/2014','12/11/2011']})
df.login_datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.login_datetime)
df.logout_datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.logout_datetime)
```

I would like to replace the timestamp `00:00:00` in logout_datetime records with corresponding `login_datetime` timestamp when the dates are matching. Please note that `00:00:00` is not always displayed in jupyter notebook

For ex: for 2nd record the dates are matching but logout timestamp is `00:00:00 AM`, So, I would like to change it to `11:21:00 AM`

I tried the below but not sure how to strip the timestamp and paste it to other column (I don't wish to copy whole column)

```
 df['ts'] =  [datetime.datetime.time(d) for d in df['login_datetime']]
 df['new_logout_time'] = df['logout_datetime'] + df['ts']
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
 login_datetime          logout_datetime
2013-05-07 09:27:00    2013-07-15 09:27:00
2013-09-08 11:21:00    2013-09-08 11:21:00
2014-06-06 08:00:00    2014-06-06 08:00:00
2014-06-06 05:00:00    2014-06-06 05:00:00
2011-12-11 10:00:00    2011-12-11 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `time`s to timedeltas, so possible add to datetimes by conditions:

```
mask = df['logout_datetime'].dt.date == df['login_datetime'].dt.date
df['ts'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['login_datetime'].dt.time.astype(str))

df['new_logout_time'] = np.where(mask,
                                 df['logout_datetime'].dt.normalize() + df['ts'],
                                 df['logout_datetime'])
print(df)
       login_datetime     logout_datetime              ts     new_logout_time
0 2013-05-07 09:27:00 2013-07-15 09:27:00 0 days 09:27:00 2013-07-15 09:27:00
1 2013-09-08 11:21:00 2013-09-08 00:00:00 0 days 11:21:00 2013-09-08 11:21:00
2 2014-06-06 08:00:00 2014-06-06 08:00:00 0 days 08:00:00 2014-06-06 08:00:00
3 2014-06-06 05:00:00 2014-06-06 00:00:00 0 days 05:00:00 2014-06-06 05:00:00
4 2011-12-11 10:00:00 2011-12-11 00:00:00 0 days 10:00:00 2011-12-11 10:00:00
```

Or without new column:

```
mask = df['logout_datetime'].dt.date == df['login_datetime'].dt.date
ts = pd.to_timedelta(df['login_datetime'].dt.time.astype(str))

df['new_logout_time'] = np.where(mask,
                                 df['logout_datetime'].dt.normalize() + ts,
                                 df['logout_datetime'])
print(df)
       login_datetime     logout_datetime     new_logout_time
0 2013-05-07 09:27:00 2013-07-15 09:27:00 2013-07-15 09:27:00
1 2013-09-08 11:21:00 2013-09-08 00:00:00 2013-09-08 11:21:00
2 2014-06-06 08:00:00 2014-06-06 08:00:00 2014-06-06 08:00:00
3 2014-06-06 05:00:00 2014-06-06 00:00:00 2014-06-06 05:00:00
4 2011-12-11 10:00:00 2011-12-11 00:00:00 2011-12-11 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.mask()` to conditionally copy the datetime from `login_datetime` to `logout_datetime`, as follows:

```
df['logout_datetime'] = df['logout_datetime'].mask(df['logout_datetime'].dt.date == df['login_datetime'].dt.date, df['login_datetime'])
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)


       login_datetime     logout_datetime
0 2013-05-07 09:27:00 2013-07-15 09:27:00
1 2013-09-08 11:21:00 2013-09-08 11:21:00
2 2014-06-06 08:00:00 2014-06-06 08:00:00
3 2014-06-06 05:00:00 2014-06-06 05:00:00
4 2011-12-11 10:00:00 2011-12-11 10:00:00
```

**Edit**

To extract the time of `login_datetime`, you can use:

```
df['ts'] = df['login_datetime'].dt.time
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted. Is there anyway to do it by stripping timestamp instead of copying? Because am doing this task only because copying doesn't work effectively...For some records, I still get `00:00:00`

Comment: I would prefer strip approach than copy approach

Comment: @TheGreat  Stripping timestamp then you will only leave with date without time ?  Is this what you want ?

Comment: No, I mean strip/extract the timestamp (`11:21:00`) from login_datetime and append/attach it to `logout_datetime`.. Retain original datetime variables as is but create some intemediate variables

Comment: @TheGreat  You can try extracting the time by `dt.time`  e.g. `df['login_datetime'].dt.time`

Comment: @SeaBean - So last is only changed `dt.normalize() ` like my solution ? :(

Comment: Can you add for `EDIT` - like another answer? Or please change your solution, not like me.

Comment: @jezrael  2 main difference:s  1) `ts` is maintained as time not timedelta.   2) the mask is checking `df['logout_datetime'].dt.normalize() == df['logout_datetime']`.   The syntax is similar using np.where but underlying entries are different.

Comment: Basically it is EDIT copied from me, only differencie is date vs normalize comparing, what is same ouput. So can you change more your EDIT?

Comment: @jezrael  If you don't like, I removed the edit.